# Multiple parameters in validation curve for sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to use the validation_curve function in sklearn.

```
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(DecisionTreeClassifier(), X_train, y_train,
param_name="max_depth",
scoring="f1",                                          
param_range=list(range(5,15,2)),
cv=5)
```

Is there a way I can pass multiple parameters to plot this curve. For example

```
param_name=["max_depth","min_samples_split"]
```

I checked online and I couldnt find such examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html states that you have to input:

**param_name** : string
Name of the parameter that will be varied.

**param_range** : array-like, shape (n_values,)
The values of the parameter that will be evaluated.

implying that you cannot provide more than one parameter to vary and test.
In fact, the resulting plot is bivariate, being the ordinal axis the score metric and the abscissa the variation of your parameter.

I believe you could fit two parameters by testing one while holding fixed the other, i.e. creating multiple validation curves for different values of the first parameter that you fix when declaring the estimator.

Such an approach, translated into code, could read:

```
max_depth_range = list(range(5, 15, 2))
min_samples_split = list(range(2, 10, 1))

for k in min_samples_split:
    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=k), 
                                                 X_train, y_train,
                                                 param_name="max_depth",
                                                 scoring="f1",                                          
                                                 param_range=max_depth_range,
                                                 cv=5)
    #do something here with train_scores & test_scores
```

Comment: it takes an extremly long time to plot this - could you not just plot the resulst from grid search?

Comment: Actually you are exploring the validation curve for different settings of your DecisionTreeClassifier, you do need to iterate through such different sets. To shorten the time it takes, you have to act on the cv folds (by reducing them) or sample your training data.

Comment: so sorry you are saying i need to use validation curve? how long did it take you to run the above.. many thanks..